# How to add field in ng-form, if this field is located out of ng-form (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I have:

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
  <input...>
  <input...>
  <input...>
</ng-form>

<special-field ng-model="myField" />
```

and I need to add 'special-field' in ng-form using directive (It is for $dirty and $valid).

I've tried to get ngModelController of ng-form:

```
.directive('specialField', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

          var formCtrl = angular.element(document).find('ng-form').controller('name');
          var field = element.controller('ngModel');

          formCtrl.$addControl(field);
        }
    };
}]);
```

But getting controller of ng-form is not working by 'name'.

1. Why is 'getting by name' not working?
2. Are there other ways to add field to form?

Comment: The `special-field` directive isn't a parent of the form, so the `element.find('ng-form')` should found nothing.

Comment: Yes. I've changed to `angular.element(document).find('ng-form')`